# CSS files are can't resolve in Migration of Angular JS 1.7 and Angular 17 hybrid model application

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-5, angular17

[webpack-cli] ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve css in directoty\src folder

Webpack version is 5.89.0

I am expecting the correct syntax of loading CSS, JS and TS files from webpack

DEP_WEBPACK_CONFIGURATION_NO_EMIT_ON_ERRORS DeprecationWarning: Optimization.noEmitOnErrors is deprecated in favor of optimization.emitOnErrors